# how can I list all procedures in voltdb?

Tags: procedure, voltdb

I want to find that what procedure I have defined before, so how can I list all procedures in `voltdb`?

which cmd should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can browse the procedures in the VoltDB Management Console web interface, or in sqlcmd you can use the command "list procedures".

Answer (score 0):

```
show procedures;
```

Bottom you will see > User Procedures

Later you can delete `drop procedure <Name>`